# findAll() in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa-2.0, crud-repository

When I try to select all details of my database, I don't get data s into a table structure in my jsp page. The array is printed in my jsp but  don't know how to make it single objects.

Here is my mapping

```
    @RequestMapping("/viewall")
    public ModelAndView findAll(ModelAndView mav){
            
       List<aswathyDTO>li= dao.findAll();
       for (aswathyDTO aswathyDTO : li) {
          System.out.println(li);
       }
       mav.addObject("li",li);
       mav.setViewName("li");
    
       return new ModelAndView("displayall.jsp","li",li);
    }
```

and here is my jsp page

```html
<body>
${li }

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <c:forEach items="${li}" var="li">
      <tr>
        <td>${li.id}</td>
        <td>${li.name}</td>
        <td>${li.age}</td>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: You are using the same parameter for your list as the individual elements, that isn't going to work. Next to that your controller is strange/wrong. You are adding things to the `ModelAndView` and then generate a new one?

Comment: but i get data from adding ${li} this in the jsp body

Comment: And assign the single elements to `li` which overwrites the list, breaking stuff. As mentioned in the answer your `items` and `var` should be different.

Comment: i edited the code like this                                                                                                        
 for (aswathyDTO aswathyDTO : list) {
 }
 mav.addObject("li",list);
 mav.setViewName("li");
 return new ModelAndView("displayall.jsp","li",list);
 }                                                                                 
  <c:forEach items="${li}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.id}</td>
        <td>${element.name}</td>
        <td>${element.age}</td>
  </c:forEach>but it shows the empty jsp page with table heads only

Answer (score 1):

Your JSP should look like this:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
  <c:forEach items="${li}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.id}</td>
        <td>${element.name}</td>
        <td>${element.age}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
```

Also make sure that you import the standard library:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: i have tried this but the table data is showing  empty like this     id  name  age

Comment: Can you please provide the full jsp file

Comment: <body>

<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
  <c:forEach items="${li}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.id}</td>
        <td>${element.name}</td>
        <td>${element.age}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>


</body>

Comment: No the whole file with all imports

Comment: <%@page import="com.example.demo.dao.RegisterDAO"%>
<%@page import="com.example.demo.model.aswathyDTO"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
  <c:forEach items="${li}" var="element">
    <tr>
        <td>${element.id}</td>
        <td>${element.name}</td>
        <td>${element.age}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>

Comment: Checkout my updated answer

Comment: this error occured.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: spring boot 4 in spring tool suite

Comment: Please checkout https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp